# Flicker in google map marker animation

Tags: google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers

I have done a part of a website with google map, animated markers. I am using a custom image of size 160X243px as the marker icon. I put the bounce animation in the `mouseover` event, And remove the animation on `mouseout`. The problem is I got some jerk at the starting of the animation, Its like get blurred on the begining. Is there any way to avoid this. I have set a delay to resolve this but it is not much helpful.The following is the code I used for animation.

> WITH OUT DELAY

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            });
```

> WITH DELAY

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {

             setTimeout(function() {
                  addMarkerMethod1();
                },  400);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {  
         setTimeout(function() {
      addMarkerMethod2();
    },  100);
    });


        function addMarkerMethod1()
        {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }

        function addMarkerMethod2()
        {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the issue in a working demo using jsfiddle?

Comment: I am not able to post it in jsfiddle, But I could provide a Link

http://export.idreamzsolutions.net/brewhousecafe/

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to avoid the flicker in to an extend, But sill it got some flickering. Please let me know, if this code can be improved again

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() { 
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    addMarkerMethod1();
                                           },400);});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {  
                     setTimeout(function() {
                         addMarkerMethod2();
                                               },  100);});

                        function addMarkerMethod1()
                        {       
                              marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);                            
                        }
                        function addMarkerMethod2()
                        {
                                marker.setAnimation(null);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably that the mouseover event is called twice, as long as you stay over the market (so the animation is called many times, causing the flickering).

You can try to remove the mouseover event and re-add it on mouseout :

```
var overEvent = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", doBounce);

function doBounce() {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(overEvent);
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
    overEvent = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", doBounce);
    marker.setAnimation(null);
});
```

**EDIT : Doesn't work. Because the animation makes the mouse call out event (by moving the marker, your mouse is not yet over it...). And the gmaps API doesn't tell anything about animations events, like 'complete' etc. So it will be complicated and very tricky to accomplish.**

Comment: Thanks, But its not working.Do we have mouseenter/mouseleve for markers?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: Thanks, But it still fails in google chrome(Version 23.0.1271.64 )